# backbone.js is not saving model with updated attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, titanium-mobile

```
usersCollection.fetch({
    success: function () {
        var getModel = usersCollection.where(checkIDJSON);
        //update that partcular attribute
        getModel.set('interest', 'rolling stones');
        console.log("Users:" + usersCollection.toJSON());

    },
    error: function () {
        // something is wrong..
    }

});
```

After running the code, it complains that the function is undefined, when trying to save to the model. Any idea why? thanks

I am using backbone.js in titanium mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where):

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed **attributes**.

So when you say this:

```
var getModel = usersCollection.where(checkIDJSON);
```

you end up with an array of models in `getModel`. If you're sure that there will only be one model that matches, then use [`findWhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere):

> **findWhere** `collection.findWhere(attributes)`
>
> Just like *where*, but directly returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed **attributes**.

like this:

```
var getModel = usersCollection.findWhere(checkIDJSON);
```

If there could be multiple matches then presumably you'd want to call `set` on each one.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have changed the code to findWhere, but still it is complaining that Undefined is not a function evaluating collection.findWhere(checkIDJSON);

Comment: Which version of Backbone do you have? Are you sure that `usersCollection` is a Backbone collection instance?